# WPF Application not atuhenticated to WEB API using ADAL

Tags: wpf, azure, adal

I have tried following several ADAL (Azure AD Authentication Library) examples to get my WPF application to call an Azure secured Web API.  Everything appears to work fine.  I receive the login prompt, it accepts my credentials, I'm able to acquire a token.  I attach the token to my request but the request always returns the HTML for the Azure login page as if I'm not authenticated.

Has anyone else experienced this type of issue?  Are there certain things I should be checking for?

Comment: If you have access to the backend API project you can just plant some breakpoints and debug the old fashioned way. Other than that, do you have any code that could be used to demonstrate how you're calling the API and how the API *should* respond to your request?

Comment: Breakpoints on the API project don't work because it's never making it that far.  It's hitting the Azure security and never making it to my controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are securing your API using a redirect based protocol instead of the oauth bearer. For a discussion on the differences between the two see http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2014/04/22/authentication-protocols-web-ux-and-web-api/.
The canonical WPF sample is in https://github.com/AzureADSamples/NativeClient-DotNet. See how the web API is secured.

Comment: Yes, my API runs in the same project as my website.  It appears that the authentication added by VS when setting up the website works for accessing the site but not for allowing access to the API.  I was able to resolve the issue by adding in OWIN Active Directory NuGet package and creating a Startup.cs file